# How can I make multiple entries on one page with this code

Tags: javascript

**This is the html file:**

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit:wght@300&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <script src="index2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="header"></p>
    <br />

    <div id="about"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**This is the css file:**

```
body {
  background-color: #004c97;
  color: #ffcd00;
  font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
  }

#header {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

**This is the JavaScript file:**

```
/*const welcText = "The National FFA Organization";
    var i = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (i >= welcText.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      } else {
        document.getElementById("header").innerHTML += welcText[i];
        i++;
      }
    }, 100);
    
    const abtText =
      "FFA is a dynamic youth organization that changes lives and prepares members for premier leadership, personal growth and career success through agricultural education.";
    i = 0;
    if (i >= abtText.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
      document.getElementById("about").innerHTML += abtText[i];
      i++;
    }
    */
    
    async function writeTextToElem(str, elem) {
      for (let char of str) {
        elem.innerHTML += char;
        await delay(100);
      }
    }
    
    async function delay(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
      });
    }
    
    (async function() {
      const headerElem = document.querySelector('.header');
      const paragraphElem = document.querySelector('.about');
      
      await writeTextToElem("Welcome", headerElem);
      await writeTextToElem("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", paragraphElem);
```

I'm trying to have something like this, and this is just a roughly typed, text only example:

guide: \ =100 ms delay **/** _ = space

(centered)W\e\l\c\o\m\e\ _t\o\ _m\y\ _S\A\E.

(below the title, and it needs to start 2 seconds after the title finishes typing out[i'm not going to write out the boring agriculture text]) S\o\m\e\ _t\e\x\t\ _s\o\m\e _\t\e\x\t\ _s\o\m\e _t\e\x\t.

I want to be able to do this with multiple paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function writeTextToElem(str, elem) {
  for (let char of str) {
    elem.innerHTML += char;
    await delay(100);
  }
}

async function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

(async function() {
  const headerElem = document.querySelector('#header');
  const paragraphElem = document.querySelector('#paragraph');
  
  await writeTextToElem("Welcome", headerElem);
  await writeTextToElem("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", paragraphElem);
})()
```

```css
.header {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.paragraph {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="paragraph"></div>
```

Comment: this didn't seem to work in codesandbox. im using this for a school project. im making an agriculture website. let me edit post and send full code. or do i need a new post for this?

Comment: Just editing it is good.

Comment: It has been about half an hour and I'm not seeing an edit to your post so, before I go to bed, let me leave you with one last bit of advice. Go ask https://chat.openai.com/chat for help with your code. I think you'll be blown away by how helpful it can be.